# Hide and Show in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, styles, visible

I am new in angularJs .

This is my bit level view

```
<input type="text" ng-model="todoName" size="30"
            placeholder="Add Your Name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoAge" size="30"
            placeholder="Add Your Age">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="todoId" />
        <form style="display:'?????????'" ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
        </form>
         <form style="display:'?????????'" ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="update">
        </form>
```

and this is my angularjs bit level coding

```
$scope.DisplayUpdate = "none";
```

I have one screan for  manage student details, i want to show add button when first time at this time hide update button , and when update time to show update button and at this time add button was need to hide .

see this line for set to hide and show details in script side using angular js :  `$scope.DisplayUpdate = "none";`

How to i set this value in my button style ?

```
 <form style="display:'?????????'" ng-submit="addTodo()">
                <input class="btn-primary" style="display:'?????????'" type="submit" value="add">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` to hide it

```
<form ng-show="DisplayUpdate === 'none'" ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

If you want to remove it from DOM tree, use ng-if

```
<form ng-if="DisplayUpdate === 'none'" ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

Comment: @RameshRajendran yes, `ng-show` `ng-if` accept an expression that return a Boolean value. You can pass a complex expression or a function.

Comment: Yes , I finished that , see this my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19176872/2218635

Comment: You should mention that ng-if is only available in the unstable branch, from version 1.1.5 and up. If you're on earlier versions you need angular-ui to provide it (but not the newest version of anguar-ui where it was removed because it was introduced in the newest versions of angular). Alternatively you achieve the same with ng-switch in a much more verbose way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the style directly, use the ng-show directive and let Angular handle it for you.

[API Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)

Comment: No problem :) Usually when you try to do something in an imperative way, there's a declarative angular solution you can use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it .

Below is my code :

JS file :

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    var value = BindStudentList();
    function BindStudentList() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Contact1',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                value = data.data;
            }
        });
        $scope.DisplaySave = true;
        $scope.DisplayUpdate = false;
        return value;
    }

    $scope.addTodo = function () {      
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index1',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { todoName: $scope.todoName, todoAge: $scope.todoAge },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                value = data.data;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.Sample = value;
    $scope.remaining = function () {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.Sample, function (todo) {
            count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });
        return count;
    };

    $scope.editTodo = function (Student) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Edit1',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { Id: Student.todo.StudentId },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $scope.todoName = data.data.StudentName;
                $scope.todoAge = data.data.StudentAge;
                $scope.todoId = data.data.StudentId;
                $scope.DisplayUpdate = true;
                $scope.DisplaySave = false;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

and this is my view code

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <h2>Student Details</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <span>{{remaining()}} of {{Sample.length}} remaining</span>
        [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoName" size="30"
            placeholder="Add Your Name">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoAge" size="30"
            placeholder="Add Your Age">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="todoId" />
        <form ng-show="DisplaySave" ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
        <form ng-show="DisplayUpdate" ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Student Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Student Age</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="todo in Sample">
                <td><span>{{todo.StudentName}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{todo.StudentAge}}</span></td>
                <td>
                    <button value="{{todo.StudentId}}" ng-click="editTodo(this)">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the `ng-show="DisplaySave"` and `ng-show="DisplayUpdate"` in my buttons , and i will pass the values like `true` or `false` in **javascript** using **angularjs** when edit and load time .

Now it's working.  I know my code will helps to other person . cheers